# Swagger UI Limit Post Body Parameter

Tags: .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

How to limit swagger UI body parameters?

```
public class MstUser : BaseModel
{
    [Primary]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string SaltText { get; set; }
    public DateTime PasswordExpireDate { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public AccountController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this._account = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAccount>();
    }
    [HttpPost, Route("RegisterUser")]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(SecuredController))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(MstUser data)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _account.RegisterUser(data);
            response.Result = string.Format(ApiMessage.SuccessfullyRegistered, "User");
            return ApiResponse(ResponseMessage.Success, response);
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ShowError(ex);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost, Route("Login")]
    [ParameterAttribute(RequiredParameter = "UserName,Password")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] MstUser data)
    {
        try
        {
            var IpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            var response = await _account.Login(data, IpAddress);
            return ApiResponse(ResponseMessage.Success, response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ShowError(ex);
        }
    }
```

the swagger UI will show as follows :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuObF.png)

How to limit property allowed/displayed by swagger so that for example :

Login -> only show username and password

Register -> only show username, password, shortname, fullname

I see that header can easily modified but body is not at IRequestBodyFilter

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: it's Swashbuckle